# How to split string from a specific character in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a dataframe with emails. I want to get the characters after @ and put it into another column. How I can do that in SQL?

Ex:

> **Email**
>
> ana@gmail.com
>
> will@yahoo.com

*Output*

> **New column**
>
> gmail.com
>
> yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(email, '@', -1) as domain
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres:

```
select split_part(email, '@', 2)
from (values ('ana@gmail.com')) t1(email);
```

will work and return an empty string if there is no `'@'`

or a less elegant alternative...

```
select right(email, (length(email) - position('@' in email))) 
from (values ('ana@gmail.com')) t1(email);
```

will also work and return the original string if there is no `'@'`